# Code signing in CI builds with USB token based private key

Tags: windows, ssl, continuous-integration, code-signing

I've recently acquired a code signing certificate, and due to new best practices it was delivered on a USB token, with an inaccessible private token. My goal is to use this in CI builds, but I'm a little unsure what the best way to move forward is.

I've seen a few guides that mention using a product like VirtualHere that allows remote access to a usb port, but that seems a little annoying for automated builds.

https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/code-signing-with-usb-tokens

Is it possible to create a sort of subordinate code signing cert/key that is signed by the "root" key on the USB token?

I have the setup more or less working locally, even via CI builds, but I would prefer to not run CI builds on my personal laptop...

Does anyone have any experience with USB tokens for code signing in CI builds?